# Angular - Create Validators efficiently

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, formbuilder

I am using [Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) and currently I have the following code:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  dob: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  gender: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  address: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
```

Basically I have 3 forms which have the same Validators. Is there a way I can make this more efficient? I do not want to have repetitive code like this.

For example, can I loop inside `formBuilder.group` in order to create the same validator for each of those forms?

Comment: There is no way to make that code less verbose, otherwise consider using template-driven form

Comment: If your forms are simple you can use dynamic form concept https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form otherwise you can use group validator